# Printing out element of array, it shows hash code instead of value

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the class. The static method `findMax` returns `arr[maxIndex]` and when I try to print that out in the main method I get a memory location instead of the value. I thought to print out a value at a certain index of an array.

I would like to print the value, but without changing the existing method
(so I have to fix the problem via the main).

```
public class Problem1 
 {
     public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> AnyType findMax(AnyType[] arr) 
    {
        int maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            if ( arr[i].compareTo(arr[maxIndex]) > 0 )
               maxIndex = i;
        return arr[maxIndex];
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(1,2);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(2,2);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(3,2);
        Rectangle rect4 = new Rectangle(4,2);
        Rectangle rect5 = new Rectangle(5,3);

        Rectangle[ ] rectangles = new Rectangle[5];
        rectangles[0] = rect1;
        rectangles[1] = rect2;
        rectangles[2] = rect3;
        rectangles[3] = rect4;
        rectangles[4] = rect5;

        System.out.println(findMax(rectangles));

    }

}
```

Comment: *Presumably* you need to `Override` `toString` in `Rectangle`.

Comment: Look into using `Arrays.toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `findMax()` method returns a `Rectangle`. By default, Java does not know how to print a `Rectangle`. So you need to override `toString()` on that class. Currently, the default, `Object.toString()` is being used, which simply prints the hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

Override toString method of Rectangle class